# php function to refresh page with requested time

Tags: php

So there is a page which needs to refresh as per a user want to.

Now if they want to refresh the page for ten times, what they should do rather than reload the page?

I want something like `xyz.com/abc.php?refresh=10`

where `$refresh=[no. of time requested]`

How to do that  ?

Comment: `header("Refresh:10; url=abc.php");` you can try this

Comment: Thanks for the reply . But I guess It will fix the refresh amount. Where as I want to execute it as per I input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a `Refresh` header to tell the page to refresh. Subtract 1 from the number of refreshes so it will count down.

```
if (isset($_GET['refresh']) && int($_GET['refresh']) > 1) {
    $_GET['refresh']--;
    header("Refresh: $refresh_seconds; {$_GET['refresh']}");
}
```

where `$refresh_seconds` is how many seconds it should wait before refreshing.

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out what you're doing from that comment. You need to post a real question with the code. If SO won't let you post a new question, you have to wait until you're able.